# Not showing the output in the App it is showing log indefined in the console

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I am using `console.log(result)` is it showing me output in the console log but not showing output in the app when I try to `console.log(result.content)`

Using react native and a quote api [Link: https://api.quotable.io/quotes/random](https://api.quotable.io/quotes/random)  you can see this response:

### LOG

[{"_id": "tvXaBe-wkKU", "author": "Octavia E. Butler", "authorSlug": "octavia-e-butler", **"content": "Sometimes being a friend means mastering the art of timing. There is a time for silence. A time to let go and allow people to hurl themselves into their own destiny. And a time to prepare to pick up the pieces when it's all over."**, "dateAdded": "2020-07-10", "dateModified": "2023-04-14", "length": 229, "tags": ["Friendship"]}]

while using logging result works but logging `console.log(result.content)` outputs undefined

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from "react-native";

const App = () => {
  const [Quote, setQuote] = useState("Loading...");
  const [Author, setAuthor] = useState("Loading...");
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  const randomQuote = () => {
    setIsLoading(true);

    fetch("https://api.quotable.io/quotes/random")
      .then((res) => {
        if (!res.ok) {
          throw new Error(`Failed to fetch: ${res.status}`);
        }
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result.content);
        setQuote(result.content);
        setAuthor(result.author);
        setIsLoading(false);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error fetching quote:", error.message);
        setIsLoading(false);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    randomQuote();
  }, []);
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        backgroundColor: "#ADD8E6",
      }}
    >
      <View
        style={{
          width: "90%",
          backgroundColor: "#fff",
          borderRadius: 20,
          padding: 20,
        }}
      >
        <Text
          style={{
            color: "#333",
            textAlign: "center",
            fontSize: 26,
            fontWeight: "600",
            marginBottom: 20,
          }}
        >
          Quote of the Day
        </Text>
        <Text style={{ color: "black", fontSize: 30, fontWeight: "800" }}>
          "
        </Text>
        <Text
          style={{
            color: "purple",
            fontSize: 16,
            lineHeight: 26,
            letterSpacing: 1.1,
            fontWeight: "400",
            textAlign: "center",
            marginBottom: 10,
            paddingHorizontal: 30,
          }}
        >
          {Quote}
        </Text>
        <Text
          style={{
            color: "black",
            fontSize: 30,
            textAlign: "right",
            fontWeight: "800",
          }}
        >
          "
        </Text>
        <Text
          style={{
            textAlign: "right",
            fontWeight: "300",
            fontSize: 16,
            fontStyle: "italic",
            color: "#000",
          }}
        >
          -- {Author}
        </Text>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={randomQuote}
          style={{
            backgroundColor: "black",
            padding: 20,
            borderRadius: 30,
            marginVertical: 20,
          }}
        >
          <Text style={{ color: "#fff", fontSize: 18, textAlign: "center" }}>
            {isLoading ? "Loading..." : "New Quote"}
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your result an array not an object. So if you write

```
console.log(result[0].content)
```

you will see the content of the first item.

Answer (score 0):

As [Aslihan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17854116/asl%C4%B1han-t%C3%BCrkd%C3%B6nmez) mentioned the result from the given API call is an array of objects so.

If you only need to access the first one or if you know it will always be a single result then, `result[0].content` works perfectly.

However, if you ever have more than one quote to show then I suggest using `map()` to display instead.

**Example:**

```
const Quotes = result.map((result)=>(<div>{result.content}</div>))
```